# A group theory problem that seems wrong - am I misunderstanding the wording?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Here's the problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $N$ such that $C_{G}(N) \leq N$. Show that $|G| \leq |N|!$.

**Also, show that this upper bound is achieved when $|N|=4$. Identify $G$ in this case.**

Now, I've already proved the first part of the problem. What I'm having trouble with is the second part, I don't believe it.

Let $G = N = K_{4}$. Then all assumptions of the statement are met, and $|N| = 4$, but clearly the upper bound is not achieved. What am I missing?

Comment: You want to show that there is an example with $|N|=4$ in which the upper bound is achieved, not that the upper bound is always achieved when $|N|=4$.

Comment: Alright, thank you Dr. Magidin. I think $S_{3} \times K_{4}$ is such an example.

Comment: With what subgroup?

Comment: My initial thought was $N = \{1\} \times K_{4}$, but $C_{G}(N) \leq N$ is not true. My second thought was $N = \{1, (1 \mapsto 2)\} \times \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$, but this is not a normal subgroup. I don't think this group works anymore, because I'm out of options for normal subgroups of order $4$.

Comment: That's what I thought... I think you should be able to do with $G=S_4$, though....